# ReactJS inner JSON array object becomes null in child object when passed down as props

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So I have an original JSON element like so:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "createdTime": "2017-11-26T20:37:49.573846",
        "name": "blah blah blah"
        "holidays": [],
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "createdTime": "2017-11-26T20:37:49.573846",
                "name": "Some Mall",
                "business": {
                    "id": 1
                },
                //.....
            ]}
      }
```

The above object is fetched async and stored into a component called "Main." When I inspect it using reactJS Dev tools, the prop looks exactly as it should, it is fetched and stored correctly, all inner fields are available.

But, when I pass this prop down to a child component:

```
                    <Route path="/hours" render={()=>
                          <Hours business={this.props.business}/>
                    }/>
```

And reference it in said child component (`Hours`) as `this.props.business`, the inner JSON objects are null! (The `locations` object is now undefined, whereas in the `Main` component is is an array with 1 element and a full object as seen in the very first code example.

This is what the JSON looks like in the child component (`Hours`) of the parent component `Main` (when referenced inside of the `render()` function, but in chroem dev tools it's not missing the `locations` inner JSON, so let's say I do `console.log()` from `Hours.render()` the below is what you will see!):

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "createdTime": "2017-11-26T20:37:49.573846",
        "name": "blah blah blah"
        "holidays": [],
        "locations": {} //It used to be an array with 1 element, now it's just {}
      }
```

Here is where it is referenced in `Hours.render()`

```
render() {
    let mondayHours = this.props.business.locations[0].operationHours[0].from
```

And it causes this error: `Hours.jsx?957e:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: You should be referencing `this.props.business.locations[0].operationHours[0].from`. The component prop takes the name you give it in the JSX definition.

Comment: Take a look at this Code Sandbox project: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rro70y84m You can see that the prop is passed down (by reference) with no removal of properties.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in my code example, I changed it to `this.props.business.locations[0].operationHours[0].from` and it still results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe its because your async fetching happens after you try to use the object. Try hard-coding the object value instead of fetching async and see if it works.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle So JSON.stringify also works like that in my project. So `{JSON.stringify(this.props.business.locations)}` this prints out all of the inner fields. But when I reference them as this `(this.props.business.locations[0]` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @RupinderSingh I think you're right.